# Angular get updated value in the child control

Tags: angular

I have a parent component and I pass the main form status as input in the child component. Is there a way to keep the form status updated in the child component?

Parent HTML:

```
<app-child [status]="myFormStatus"></app-child>
```

In my child control, I use the status but when `myFormStatus` value changes in the parent, how do I inform the child about it? Is there a way to call a parent method to get the latest value?

Comment: Hey! share your ts code too.

Comment: Provide more details about what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: You can pass your form to child component and subscribe to `statusChanges`

Comment: I tried that. Strangely all my properties are not there in the form.

Comment: You should really share some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lifecycle hook that is called when any data-bound property of a directive changes. Define an `ngOnChanges()` method to handle the changes.

```
interface OnChanges {
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void
}
```

The following snippet shows how a component can implement this interface to define an on-changes handler for an input property.

```
@Component({selector: 'child-cmp', template: `...`})
class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {

  @Input() status!: any;

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    // changes.status contains the old and the new value...
    if(changes.status && changes.status.currentValue) {
     // write your logic
    }
  }
}
```

Angular provides you two Change Detection Strategies, the `default` one and the `onPush`.

With `onPush`, the component only depends on its inputs and embraces the immutability, the change detection strategy will kicks in when:
The Input reference changes;
An event originated from the component or one of its children;
Run change detection explicitly `(componentRef.markForCheck());
Use the async pipe in the view.